# how to monitor the traffic of an android

Tags: android, networking, proxy, http-proxy, network-traffic

I have an android phone that I want to monitor the HTTP/https traffic using tools like CHARLES PROXY
but the phone not on the same network as the CHARLES PROXY host. is there a way to do that without using an external server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for an external server. You need to route the traffic from your phone to the device where the intercepter is running. You could create a mitm setup with a tool like https://mitmproxy.org/. Btw you will need a routed phone, something like xposed-ProxyOn.. Then you can intercept app specific traffic. But if you try to intercept https traffic from apps they use certificate pinning you wont get a connection to the app server